# Is it ok to work with files, while Time Machine is backing them up?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, backup, time-machine

Currently, my Mac is backing all my data up.

At this time, I working ... Is it ok, when I move/change files during backup ?

Or, I will have side-effects later ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will potentially affect the backup and if it does there will be consequences.

Most of the time you should be OK as you and the backup process won't be accessing the same file.

One (minor) problem or annoyance could be if the backup has dealt a file and then you modify it before the whole process is complete. You then have a problem with that file and go to restore it - you won't have the latest version in the backup. Now depending on the frequency of your backups and the nature of the change this could be an annoyance (you've lost a minor edit) to a problem in that you've lost nearly a weeks' work.

A more serious problem could occur if you move a file during the backup. The process notes where it is, you move it, the backup then can't find the file to actually backup and it's not included at it's new location. The backup will fail, but it might not tell you that it's failed - just log the problem and move on. If you don't check the logs you wouldn't know. If you then go to restore that file later it's not there.

Now all this depends on the backup system and how it handles these cases. On a day-to-day basis for incremental backups it's probably OK to carry on working. For full backups (which I assume this is) it might be better to leave the machine to get on with it so nothing goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

On newer versions of macOS, which use Apple File System (APFS), Time Machine creates snapshots from which it performs the backup. So it is completely safe to edit files while Time Machine is backing up your computer.

### About snapshots

A snapshot is like a copy of your disk frozen in time, but it does not use any additional space. Only file changes you make after the snapshot was created consume space. A technique called copy-on-write.

By analogy, imagine your working with pen and paper. The paper is your disk, and is a fixed size, and you read, write, and erase words on it using your pen. If you lay a sheet of plastic transparency over the paper sheet you can still read all the words, and you can still write on the surface, but the writing is on the transparency not the paper. Erasing would be done using something like whiteout / tippex.

In this analogy Time Machine would layer a sheet of transparency between macOS (i.e. you) and the paper (the disk) while it reads the entire paper sheet (which no longer receives any changes). When it finishes reading the paper, it will merge the changes from the transparency into the paper sheet (more-or-less by copying them) and discard the transparency.

The "cost" (as in disk space) of the snapshot in my analogy can be measured with how much ink and whiteout you applied to the transparency. Since users don't change a big percentage of their disk in the course of a day, in practice this works really well.

(And it may also explain why Time Machine spends so long on "Finishing backup...", but I'm speculating )

- [View APFS snapshots in Disk Utility on Mac – Apple Support (UK)](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/disk-utility/dskuf82354dc/mac#:%7E:text=An%20APFS%20snapshot%20is%20a,or%20more%20associated%20APFS%20snapshots.)

### Checking if your system is using snapshots

Time machine backup running on my machine right now (macOS Ventura 13.4.1) can be seen in Disk Utility.app:

[image]

(Note that you have to enable display of APFS snapshots by clicking View -> Show APFS snapshots.)

See how the "Size" of the time machine snapshot is relatively small compared to the tidemark. The tidemark is the size of the paper in my analogy, and the size here is the amount of ink and whiteout placed on the transparency.

Here I have two snapshots because I only just configured Time Machine backups last night (new backup disk), and it has not yet finished transferring the first snapshot/backup to my external disk.